# Complexity of appending lists in racket

Tags: list, scheme, racket, complexity-theory

```
>(define (f l) l)   ;;;consider l to be a list
```

What should be complexity of this function. According to me it should be O(length l) because a new list should be created on heap and a new list is created and returned.

So if it is O(length l) then complexity of (append l1 l2) function must be O(length l1 + length l2) because

```
(define (append l1 l2)
    (if (null? l1) l2 [cons (car l1) (append (cdr l1) l2)]))
```

At the base case a new list is created on heap so it would take a time O(l2) and the recursion would take time O(l1) so total complexity O(l1 + l2)

But i was taught in class that append is O(l1) in class, so which is correct?

[Screenshot to prove that an entire new list is created on heap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW5DA.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW5DA.png) (otherwise on changing l1 or l2 l3 must have changed!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(define (f l) l)` simply returns its argument, **does not copy it**, and so its complexity is O(1), while the `append` definition that you have given copies *only* the first list, and so its complexity is O(length l1).

Consider the example that you have given: `(set! l2 '(4 5))` does not modify any list, it modifies the global variable `l2`, make it pointing to a new list. So `l3` is unchanged. You can modify a list by using `set-cdr!` or `set-car!`, and if you try this (assuming using a dialect in which you can modify lists) you will see that also `l3` is modified.

Comment: Ohh so my interpretation of set! was incorrect, thanks

Comment: But effiecent scheme implementations like Racket and Ikarus keep their arguments on a stack. How does the stack allocated arguments turn into a chain of pairs O(1)?

Answer (score 0):

Renzo assumes arguments are already in a list and some interpreters that might be right. Most imlpementations of `eval` does it like this and then the actual lambda implementation does an `evlis` before `apply`.

The most efficient Scheme implementations executes the code as a stack machine and thus every variable is just an offset pointer to the stack just as in native programs. For `(lambda l l)` to work `l` needs to be consed from all the arguments such that at the beginning of the function it has performed a `O((length n))` task and it has one stack argument with the address to that freshly created list. Then it returns that address, perhaps by leaving it on the stack.

`append` gets lists as two arguments. Thus it doesn't need to create them from the stack since the stack has two addresses. `append` makes a copy of `l1` and when `l1` is the empty list it uses the `l2` without doing anything with it as the cdr` of the last pair. As an example:

```
(define test1 '(1 2 3))
(define test2 '(4 5 6))
(define test3 (append test1 test2))
test3 ; ==> (1 2 3 4 5 6)

(eq? (cdddr test3) test2) ; ==> #t (they are the same)

(define test4 (append test1 '()))
test4 ; ==> (1 2 3)

(equal? test1 test4) ; ==> #t
(eq? test1 test4)    ; ==> #f (they just look the same)
```

Here is the steps involved with the first `append`:

```
(append '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))                        ; ==
(cons '1 (append '(2 3) '(4 5 6))                 ; ==
(cons '1 (cons '2 (append '(3) '(4 5 6)))         ; ==
(cons '1 (cons '2 (cons 3 (append '() '(4 5 6)))) ; ==
(cons '1 (cons '2 (cons 3 '(4 5 6)))              ; ==
```

As you can see it is `O((+ 1 (length l1)))`